# Silverlight - Find Controls by Name (string)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

i serach a way to find controls by a string property:

```
private void AnimationCallback(string objectName, string value)
{


}
```

is it possible to find a control in this Animation callback method about the property "objectName"?? (e.g. ellipse1)

the control should become another color in condition to the value property. The Type of the control is also unknown.

Thank you

Comment: you should try with converter

Answer (score 0):

If your method is defined in a type derived from FrameworkElement, the [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use must use instance of any control as FameworkElement for using FindName method.
Example from MSDN:

```cs
private System.Windows.Controls.Grid LayoutRoot;
public Page()
{
    System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri(
        "/SilverlightApplication1;component/Page.xaml", 
        System.UriKind.Relative));
    this.LayoutRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)
        (this.FindName("LayoutRoot")));
}
```